# WordPress using AJAX connections to third-party server

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email

I'm okay with WordPress and editing files but I've had to take over a website from the designers and I'm a bit stuck.

What they've done is create an AJAX file that is used for all website submitted forms, and all of those forms are redirected to their own servers, before being sent on to the customer.

Obviously this is not ideal for a variety of reasons, but I'm unsure how to fix it. There is a rule for each form/contact method, then a final rule at the bottom of the file that I presume applies to all the previous rules.

This is:

```
function postThis($data_to_post) {
$form_url = "https://abcdef.co.uk/__mailer/__send123456.php";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data_to_post));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $result;
}
```

I'm not sure how to replace the https (which I've changed the URL of) bit with something that will simply send the forms from the website to the website owners email address, without the intercept.

Comment: Is it worth contacting those designers to see why they did it this way? If their web server does something with those AJAX ops, is it worth finding out what their servers are doing, so functionality is not accidentally broken?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up individual jquery functions that are returned on form submit to point to a php email function.

Form:

```
<form onsubmit="return someFunction();">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function someFunction(){
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: phpMailClass.php,
      data: data,
      method: 'post',
      success: function(resp){
         // Handle the response upon success
      }
    });
}
```

Receive the user inputs in a php file then use PHP's mail() function to send the form(s) to the desired recipients.